# FirebaseError : We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM web app notification for send notification to browser.My code below.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "<API-KEY>",
    authDomain: "<AUTH-DOMAIN>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "<DATABASE>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDERID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function(){
                console.log("GRANTED");
                console.log(messaging.getToken());
                return messaging.getToken();
            })
            .then(function(token){
                console.log(token);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('Error Occurred.' + err)
            });

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
  const title = "Hello World";
  const option = { body: payload.data.status }
  return self.registration.showNotification(title,option);
});
```

It is working fine and generating token on the chrome's localhost server  but  not working on my hosting server.

I got the following error with my hosting server.

**Error Occurred.FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. The operation is insecure. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).**

Please guide me if anybody have any idea about this.

Comment: Are you using SSL in the target URL for this integration?. This is mandatory.

Comment: Hi, have you find solution, if so, can you post here ? I also facing same error.

Answer (score 27):

create **firebase-messaging-sw.js** in your root folder and paste the code in it.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Didn't help me.  Still getting "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. The operation is insecure."  launching the app from my localhost.

Comment: if you are recommending this code in firebase-messaging-sw.js and in the code is loading the same file, not sure how this is going to work!

Comment: the file  "firebase-messaging-sw.js" needs to be created inside "public" folder

Answer (score 25):

2021 working procedure with create-react-app

1. In /public folder create file firebase-messaging-sw.js with the following code:

   ```
    // Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
    importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js");
    importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js");

    // Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "YOURDATA",
      authDomain: "YOURDATA",
      projectId: "YOURDATA",
      storageBucket: "YOURDATA",
      messagingSenderId: "YOURDATA",
      appId: "YOURDATA",
      measurementId: "YOURDATA",
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    // Retrieve firebase messaging
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Received background message ", payload);

      const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
      const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
      };

      self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
    });
   ```
2. Now in app.js or wherever you needed add this code.

   ```
   /*firebase daniel start*/
   import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
   import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

   const firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "YOURDATA",
     authDomain: "YOURDATA",
     projectId: "YOURDATA",
     storageBucket: "YOURDATA",
     messagingSenderId: "YOURDATA",
     appId: "YOURDATA",
     measurementId: "YOURDATA",
   };
   const fapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   const messaging = getMessaging(fapp);

   getToken(messaging, {
     vapidKey:
       "YOURKEY",
   })
     .then((currentToken) => {
       if (currentToken) {
         console.log("Firebase Token", currentToken);
       } else {
         // Show permission request UI
         console.log(
           "No registration token available. Request permission to generate one."
         );
         // ...
       }
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
       // ...
     });

   onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
     console.log("Message received. ", payload);
     // ...
   });

   /*firebase daniel end*/
   ```

Answer (score 12):

Although there are multiple threads and closed issues for this error, this thread comes up at top of google result if this error is directly copied from console to search, hence sharing my experience here makes sense.

As the other answers suggest:

1. Make sure `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is publicly available at the host root
2. Make sure the firebase config data is correct and double checked

Even after checking all these, I got the same error.

So finally resort to google docs and this time I read carefully [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/ac2be86edba88d12fc34e4f4d91839500c7c95af/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js#L17)

**From Firebase v9, they moved to compat** as mentioned in [this commit](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/commit/4ec5cb53e7cb07ad5484eec49cc3bfce60e26da0)

So, the import scripts inside `firebase-messaging-sw.js` are now:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/<v9+>/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/<v9+>/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
```

where `<v9+>` is the Firebase SDK version above 9

Thats it done!!

Comment: My exact same case. I trusted a very old code written "some time" ago, and I only updated it by changing version numbers in importScripts to 9.22.X. The script started to throw exceptions but the message "We are unable to register" didn't show the details about that exception. I was sure the code was correct because it was working before. The solution was to add "-compat" before ".js" extension.

Answer (score 9):

Try to add the below sample in your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and put `firebase-messaging-sw.js` inside your public folder in react app.

```
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('Received background message ', payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: In the front-end part of my project, inside `public` folder of VUEJS I have added this file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

This is because service worker works either on https or localhost. So if your website is not having SSL certificate service worker will not work.

Comment: Even I am using SSL but still it is not working? And it is working with same credentials on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

most likely the HTTPd does not properly serve JS files with a content-type `application/javascript` header. cannot validate that suspicion, without any live URL - while in case of, one can either configure the MIME types for the server - or as a quick fix: set the missing content-type HTTP header with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the "firebase-messaging-sw.js" has existed in your public folder

Answer (score 2):

I am using firebase version 9.9.1
Steps to solve this issue :

1. Add new file firebase-messaging-sw.js in your project public folder
2. Add following code in firebase-messaging-sw.js
   according to firebase version  installed in your
   project:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
```

3. Restart the project

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me with version 10.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I used Amazon CloudFront to host my production environment. While it worked on localhost, I received this error on production (https). After reviewing the Amazon S3 bucket (which targeted CloudFront), I noticed that during production deployment the service worker file was not generated. Simply modifying the deployment script solved the issue.

So make sure that the service worker file is generated (Chrome DevTools -> Sources -> Filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

Im building a Reactjs Web App. I've put **an empty** file `firebase-messaging-sw.js`, as mentioned [on FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token) . The file is under /public folder. I get it working ✅

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting that error because I was missing `appId` in my `firebase.initializeApp({})`, which is also missing in your config.

Answer (score 0):

In React - we only need to create a file name `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in the public folder and the issue will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding this code inside my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in the `public` folder.

```
function requestPermission() {
  console.log('Requesting permission...');
  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    }
  });
}
```

reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error is caused because your chrome browser is pending an update. Close the browser and try again.