# Angular Firebase Cloud Messaging got service worker problems

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to implement firebase cloud messaging in my pwa that is build with angular.
When I host the app on my local server I get following Problem on my console:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Messaging: We are
> unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a
> ServiceWorker for scope
> ('http://localhost:18080/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with
> script ('http://localhost:18080/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP
> response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
> (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration). FirebaseError:
> Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker.
> Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope
> ('http://localhost:18080/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with
> script ('http://localhost:18080/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP
> response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
> (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

I can somehow access the firebasetoken with the getToken() method.
It is unclear for me what the error want to say. Maybe anyone can help me to understand the topic a bit more.

I have the basic ngsw.json service worker that was added to the project when I executed the ng pwa command. Is it neccessary to have a scond service worker like the "firebase-messaging-sw.js" when I want to add fcm? What would this serviceworker do ? And would it have an influence on the existing sw? How would they work together?

The crazy thing about the problem is that, fcm already worked in our project (back in may). Did they change something?
(In the meantime I had to put the logic into another componenent. I can only assume that the logic can not access the sw anymore. And therefore the error mentions the "scope")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FirebaseError : We are unable to register the default service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144151/firebaseerror-we-are-unable-to-register-the-default-service-worker)

Comment: While the localhost scope may be the mere problem.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I've seen this question and also tried to add firebase-messaging-sw.js that did not work but it was also just on localhost. So I assume it has something to do with the localhost scope. I will try that. Do you suggest to always add the firebase-messaging-sw as second sw?

Comment: This file is not required, unless this is being hosted on a public domain (not in some WebView)... eg. with Capacitor, one can only register the Android / iOS build, but not the web build.